# Start next job when one of the previous manual jobs are a success

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the following job structure:

```
JOB_A:
  stage: versioning
  only:
    - main

JOB_B_MANUAL:
  stage: versioning
  needs:
    - JOB_A
  only:
    - main
  when: manual
  allow_failure: true

JOB_C_MANUAL:
  stage: versioning
  needs:
    - JOB_A
  only:
    - main
  when: manual
  allow_failure: true

JOB_D_MANUAL:
  stage: versioning
  needs:
    - JOB_A
  only:
    - main
  when: manual
  allow_failure: true

JOB_E_MANUAL:
  stage: versioning
  needs:
    - JOB_B
    - JOB_C
    - JOB_D
  only:
    - main
  when: on_success
```

How can I set this up to be:

- Make JOBS B, C, D start JOB_E when one of them is manually executed and is a succes?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the doc: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when

Possible inputs:

- **on_success** (default): Run the job only when all jobs in earlier stages succeed or have allow_failure: true.
- **manual**: Run the job only when triggered manually.
- **always**: Run the job regardless of the status of jobs in earlier stages. Can also be used in workflow:rules.
- **on_failure**: Run the job only when at least one job in an earlier stage fails.
- **delayed**: Delay the execution of a job for a specified duration.
- **never**: Don’t run the job. Can only be used in a rules section or workflow: rules.

If I understood well what you want to do, this following use case is missing:
**on_at_least_one_success**: Run the job only when at least one job in earlier stages succeed. This could be a nice feature to propose ;)

However, if you do not have any concerns to put the JOB_E in a separated pipeline, here maybe a solution for you, hope it could be your workaround:

Project: my-test/ops/job-dependency

```
stages:
  - versioning

JOB_A:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - echo "JOB_A_MANUAL"  

JOB_B_MANUAL:
  stage: versioning
  script:
    - echo "do something"
  needs:
    - JOB_A
  when: manual

JOB_B_MANUAL_TRIGGER:
  stage: .post
  trigger:
    project: my-test/ops/job-dependency-child
  needs:
    - JOB_B_MANUAL

JOB_C_MANUAL:
  stage: versioning
  script:
    - echo "do something"
  needs:
    - JOB_A
  when: manual

JOB_C_MANUAL_TRIGGER:
  stage: .post
  trigger:
    project: my-test/ops/job-dependency-child
  needs:
    - JOB_C_MANUAL

JOB_D_MANUAL:
  stage: versioning
  script:
    - echo "do something"
  needs:
    - JOB_A
  when: manual

JOB_D_MANUAL_TRIGGER:
  stage: .post
  trigger:
    project: my-test/ops/job-dependency-child
  needs:
    - JOB_D_MANUAL
```

Project: my-test/ops/job-dependency-child

```
stages:
  - post

JOB_E:
  stage: post
  script:
    - echo "do something"
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the help.. this is actually the approach I went with already.

Comment: Please avoid including important information in your answer as an image whenever possible. It is not searchable, or viewable by all users. There is no reason to include an image of text instead of copying the text itself, formatting it correctly, and linking to the source.

Comment: Thanks, I agreed. I just edited my comment, replaced an image by text.